# Steps to find the files save with respect to particular jira

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, jira

please advise how from tortoise we can find how many files have been changed with regard to particular jira, please advise from both the ways through totoise svn client and if if we have installed svn plugin in from eclipse , please advise the steps I am using svn as repo version

Folks please advise for this..!any early help would be super appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're linking commits to JIRA tickets by referencing a JIRA ticket in the commit message, like "fixing bug TEST-123"?  If so, there's no easy way to look up all the commits that reference the same JIRA ticket.  In JIRA of course you can see this information, but in Subversion you'd need to get a list of all of the commit messages and then grep the JIRA ticket ID you're interested in.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up integration between JIRA and your Subversion repositories. You can use FishEye to do this most easily, or there are two add-ons in the Marketplace that do this. One from Atlassian, one not.